# Format a String in Java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Can someone guide me how to convert a string  "15000000" to "150.00"?

I tried to do it as follows :

```
public static String truncate(String str, int length) {
    // Ensure String length is longer than requested size.
    str = str.trim();
    if (str.length() > length) {
        str = str.substring(0, length - 1);
    } 
    return str;
}

private void populateDetails() throws BusinessObjectException, ParseException {
    List<PolicyProducerDetails> policyProducerDetailsList = null;; 

    if (results!=null) {
        policyProducerDetailsList = new ArrayList<PolicyProducerDetails>();
        for (Iterator<PolhierPprModel> iterator = results.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            PolhierPprModel resultPolhierPprModel = (PolhierPprModel) iterator.next();
        {

        String test = resultPolhierPprModel.getCommRate().toString();
        String test1 =truncate(test,4);
        Float test2 = Float.parseFloat(test1);
        String test3 = String.valueOf(test2);
        policyProducerDetailsLocal.setCommRateOverride(test3);
    }
```

I am getting a 150.0 but I want to make it 150.00.

Also I don't want it to be hard coded as I did.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Hi the code is not syntactically correct can you fix it?

Comment: what exactly should be done?...the code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class java.text.DecimalFormat.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");
String result = decimalFormat.format(<your float value>);
```